# Android: horizontal scroll and unknown row's number

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, grid-layout, horizontalscrollview, viewpagerindicator

```
[doubPic] [pic] ... [triplePicture] ... [column...
[triplePicture] ... [doubPic] [pic] ... [that will...
[pic][pic][pic] ... [triplePicture] ... [be seen...
[pic] [doubPic] ... [pic][pic][pic] ... [after scroll...
```

I want to make a grid like is drown above. My main problems is that picture can take: one or two or three cells. Also I don't know how many rows I should display it depends on screen height.

So could you give me some hints how to achieve my task.

Comment: Also I don't know how many columns will be on screen at the same time, because it depends on screen width.

Comment: Add code? Add picture? Add something?

Comment: pic... pic... pic... picture, please!

Comment: I don't have neither code neither picture, because I'm a little stuck. I have only idea, which I can try to explain in more details.

What I've drown above is grid. Every row has 3 cells, so:
-> in one row we can have 3 pictures and each of them takes one cell;
-> in one row we can have 2 pictures, one of them takes two cells and other takes 1 cell;
-> in one row we can have 1 picture, that takes 3 cells.